# An interesting case of Dual Boot Shenanigans. (dell inspiron 7000)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, dell

So, my harddrive recently went bust under warranty. As such, Dell shipped me a replacement. And a USB stick containing a full windows 8 installation and repair media. In the land of OEM installs and roms, that thing is a s good as gold. All the fun began when I decided to make a second partition to install Ubuntu on. Also, keep in mind that in order to boot the USB, I had to disable Secure boot, and run it in legacy mode (an option for my computer). Contrary to what I've read on this forum, it can boot win8 without UEFI no problem. The issue was when I installed Ubuntu 14.02 off of a live USB. At first it couldn't install grub properly, then after 3 install attempts it did so successfully but fried my windows boot loader. Using the windows repair tools I managed to get the boot loader working again, but now it ignored ubuntu. I used the live USB to switch the primary boot drive to the one containing GRUB, and updated GRUB so that it could find the windows 8 boot loader image. However, apon loading the win8 image though GRUB, I get a blank bergandy screen and have to force reboot.

My computer can't seem to run both Windows and Ubuntu, and I can't run UEFI because we'll, it literally doesn't exist on my computer anymore. Also, contrary to what I've read on the forum my PC can run 32 bit versions of ubuntu, even as a 64 bit machine. I have a 32 bit 12.04 boot disk that work perfectly fine. Infact, that. Disk. Seems to have been the only way to fix the boot partition problem I had earlier.

Currently, i've gon over with a fresh install of windows, there is still a dormant Ubuntu, swap, and win8 loader partitions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take some key points of your question out of order:

> I can't run UEFI because we'll, it literally doesn't exist on my computer anymore.

I think you misunderstand what UEFI is. [As described in more detail on Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) the Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) and its version-2.x variant, the Unified EFI (UEFI) is a type of firmware that has largely replaced the older [Basic Input/Output System (BIOS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) firmware. As such, a computer will have either a BIOS or an EFI/UEFI when you buy it, and it's difficult to replace one with the other. The operations you described could *not* have removed your EFI. If your computer shipped with Windows 8.x, it almost certainly used UEFI, and continues to do so. Ditto for most computers introduced in mid-2011 and later, even if they shipped with Windows 7 (or Linux or nothing at all).

You might be thinking of the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which as the name implies, is a partition on your hard disk. As such, the ESP can be deleted. The ESP stores EFI boot loaders, so if you completely wiped and re-partitioned your disk, it might now lack an ESP. That does *not* eliminate the EFI/UEFI, though.

> in order to boot the USB, I had to disable Secure boot, and run it in legacy mode (an option for my computer).

Was this the Windows USB drive or an Ubuntu USB drive? If the latter, how did you create it?

Most EFIs provide a Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which is an EFI component that enables the EFI to use boot loader code designed for BIOSes. A CSM is to an EFI something like what WINE or DOSEMU is to Linux -- a way for one environment (EFI or Linux) to run code designed for another one (BIOS or DOS/Windows). Enabling the CSM (aka "legacy mode" or "BIOS mode") support in the firmware makes it possible to boot BIOS-mode media, but at the cost of added complexity -- the number of paths the boot process can take rises dramatically, as I explain in more detail on [this Web page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) This complexity means that the boot process becomes unpredictable when the CSM is enabled -- at least, unless you understand the idiosyncracies of *your specific* computer, which of course people posting on the Internet will not. My view of the CSM has become increasingly negative as I've read more and more accounts of problems it's created for people. In most cases, they end up fumbling around in the dark until they stumble across a solution.

In any event, it seems odd (but not impossible) to me that a Windows 8 boot medium provided by a manufacturer would boot only in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, since such computers almost always ship configured to boot in EFI/UEFI mode. Ubuntu boot media are another matter, since USB-writing tools may drop the EFI boot loader or otherwise make it difficult or impossible to boot in EFI mode. In either event, I think it's worth taking the time to figure out what's going on and get both Windows and Ubuntu installation media to boot in EFI mode. If that proves impossible, it's imperative that they both boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Having one installation in EFI mode and the other in BIOS mode is a recipe for frustration.

> The issue was when I installed Ubuntu 14.02 off of a live USB. At first it couldn't install grub properly, then after 3 install attempts it did so successfully but fried my windows boot loader.

This doesn't really tell us what the state of your computer is. Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (also available in the `boot-info-script` package in Ubuntu). This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here. The information from the Boot Info Script should provide a good idea of your computer's current state, which is required to provide a solution that's more than guesswork. At this point, my guess is that you've got a BIOS-mode Windows install and an EFI-mode Ubuntu install, but it might be the other way around or even something else entirely (matched-mode installs with boot problems that have some other cause).

Alternatively, you could start again fresh -- figure out which boot mode you're using (BIOS or EFI) for both your Windows and Ubuntu media, adjust them until they both use the same boot mode, and re-install both OSes in the same boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

Every 64bit x86 CPU can run 32bit x86 instructions, so there is nothing special about that...

AFAIK, 64bit UEFI **only** works with 64bit Ubuntu. I think when dual booting with Windows 8, using UEFI is the best alternative.

> I can't run UEFI because we'll, it literally doesn't exist on my computer anymore.

How do you mean that? If you didn't do a FW downgrade to a Legacy BIOS only firmware, you should be able to reenable UEFI in your BIOS setup.

So wipe the hard drive (if you have important files, **have a backup**), install your Windows and Ubuntu both in 64bit and with UEFI enabled, and it will more likely work out than what you did.

Comment: What I mean, is that UEFI can't recognise any boot option besides network. It seeems the Dell firmware is set up to only recognise the OEM it comes with. I had a similar problem with getting locked out of the BIOS, and I had to install a new bios rom.

Comment: Also, update. I've tried installing both Ubuntu, and Windows, with UEFI enabled, and. Neither instalation can be picked up it would seem. The only bootable media it can read is my Ubuntu USB. 

So, now I have a working instalation of windows, but I can't access my ubuntu instalation (which I installed after windows)

Comment: Again, update. I've been able to fix the dual boot issue by running over my current Ubuntu installation with the OEM version. GRUB now can boot windows (albeit the UEFI is still wacky, im in legacy mode still) Now, is there anyway to revert it. To the normal mode/version without installing again?

Comment: Some UEFI support booting Legacy OS. If yours doesn't, it will be hard to set up...

Comment: Not sure you can convert Windows from Legacy to UEFI once installed. Windows only boots with BIOS from MBR(msdos) partitioned drives and only with UEFI from gpt partitioned drives. Did you not get a UEFI Dell image that restores gpt with all the partitions Windows needs? I just installed to a new Dell SFF system. After several backups, Dell, Windows & full system, shrinking NTFS with Windows and creating partitions with gparted for Ubuntu, it then only took about 10 minutes to do actual Ubuntu install in UEFI boot mode.